# Installing a required Jar file and optionally a second jar file in Maven into the local repository

Tags: maven

I have a product that contains a Jar file in its distribution and I have created a pom.xml that uses the [install-file mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) to install the Jar into the local repository. So the user unpacks my zip file and types "mvn install" and everything works.

My problem is I have a second Jar file that I would also like to install using the same pom.xml, but this Jar file is optional and may or may not be present (the Jar file is downloaded separately by the user and placed in the same directory). I have tried install-file and also [build-helper:attach-artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) and can't figure out how to do this within a single POM. I'm happy to have the user type some different command to install this Jar file, or have it work with "mvn install".

Comment: How about a shell script/batch file which checks for the existence of this optional jar and then calls `mvn install`?

Comment: Well I suppose that would work if I made an alternate pom.xml file, but I'm trying to do something nice and clean and maven-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles), which gets activated based on the existence of the second jar.  This profile can be used to attach an additional artifact using the [build helper maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) goal that you have referred above.  Something like this...

```
<project>
  ...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>second-jar</id>
          <activation>
             <file>
              <exists>${basedir}/location/of/second.jar</exists>          
             </file>
          </activation>
          <build>
            <plugins>
              ...
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <artifacts>
                        <artifact>
                          <file>second</file>
                          <type>jar</type>
                        </artifact>
                      </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
               </executions>
             </plugin>
          </plugins>
       </build>
     </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```